# Interchanging some value within an array and pushing it to different index

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, dynamic-arrays

For an example:

I have a list of array which holds value as:

```
let data = [
"10-45-23:45", 
"10-45-22:45",
"10-45-20:45",
"10-45-23:45",
"10-45-23:59,00:00-04:59", 
"10-45-23:59, 00:00-04:59",
"10-45:22:45"
]
```

So, what I am trying to solve is anything that's after a comma inside an index i.e. the 00:00-04:59 needs to be pushed one index downwards. So, that the data can be formatted in the proper format.
I there any dynamic way how we could fix this?

My Desired Output:

```
let data = [
    "10-45-23:45", 
    "10-45-22:45",
    "10-45-20:45",
    "10-45-23:45",
    "10-45-23:59", 
    " 00:00-04:59,10-45-23:59",
    "00:00-04:59,10-45:22:45"
];
```

then sort the data to:

```
let data = [
    "10-45-23:45", 
    "10-45-22:45",
    "10-45-20:45",
    "10-45-23:45",
    "10-45-23:59", 
    "10-45-23:59,00:00-04:59",
    "10-45:22:45,00:00-04:59"
];
```

However, If the data array is already in the below-mentioned format then we do no changes to the array:

```
let data = [
 "10-45-23:59,00:00-01:59",
 "10-45:22:59,00:00-02:59",
 "10-45-23:59,00:00-04:59",
 "10-45:22:59,00:00-04:59",
 "10-45-23:59,00:00-04:59",
 "10-45:22:59,00:00-04:59",
 "10-45-23:59,00:00-04:59",
 "10-45:22:59,00:00-04:59"
]
```

Comment: what is the required format - please show it in the question as your description is vague - at a guess you want `data.flatMap(v => v.split(/,\s?./))`

Comment: Please add the expected result for this input.

Comment: So you sometimes have a space after the comma and sometimes not?

Comment: *"...then sort the data to:"*:  this seems wrong, the items that started with "00" are back at their previous positions. Can you check?

Comment: They have moved a index lower and if the last index has the value with 00:00 then it has to move to the 1st index. Please have a look at the question I have updated the body properly.

Comment: I don't understand. The first operation moves the those "00" times **in the front** of the next item, but then when you sort, they move back to the **end** of the item. You lost me. Do you mean the **pair** should be sorted, or the outer array should be sorted? Either way, that is not what I see happening in the sorted output. In my book "00" comes before "10" when you sort...

Comment: Yes, the “00:00-04-59” moves one index downward and just to match up the format. We sort the pair of the index that is from “00:00-04:59, 10:45-23:59” to “10:45-23:59, 00:00-04:59”

Answer (score 1):

You can split each value by comma (and optional white space after it), and then use `reduce` to shift those second parts to become the first parts at the next index. If at the end of that loop there is still a remainder, it is inserted at the first array value:

```js
let data = [
    "10-45-23:45", 
    "10-45-22:45",
    "10-45-20:45",
    "10-45-23:45",
    "10-45-23:59,00:00-04:58", 
    "10-45-23:59, 00:00-04:59",
    "10-45:22:45"
];

let result = data.map(s => s.split(/,\s*/));
// Only change something when there is an item that does not have doubly entry
if (result.some(({length}) => length < 2)) { // must rotate second items
    let overflow;
    [result, overflow] = result.reduce(([acc, prev], parts) =>
        [[...acc, [...prev, parts.shift()].join(",")], parts]
    , [[], []]);
    // What drops off at the end, should be inserted at the start
    result[0] = [...overflow, result[0]].join(",");
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please, like commented earlier, update your question and add the desired output.

Comment: Updated, please have a look

Comment: What if the *last* item has such a second part?

Comment: then it needs to be pushed to the first index. one more thing if all the index have the last part then nothing is to be done. I have tried my best to solve this problem but, I couldn't get any soltuion.

Comment: Oh there's a lot more rules now. Can you please edit your question and mention all those extra rules, and give examples to illustrate each rule?

Comment: Updated, please have a look